# PSQL Import to CSV Converting One Column to Integer

Tags: csv, import, psql

I have a daily routine that copies raw data (CSV) from an S3 bucket to a server and imports that raw data to a Postgresql database using COPY. The table that is being imported to has a column of type integer and unfortunately the corresponding column in the raw data is of type float. An attempt to import results in an error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer. Is there a way to cast or convert the raw data float column within the COPY command to type integer?

Fastest and easiest solution was to alter the table that was being imported to but unfortunately I cannot do this as it is not allowed (policy and business rules).